# How to get ConnectableObservable when using lettable publishLast operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I refactor this bit:

```
  const warmObservable = this.httpClient.get<Result[]>(url).publishLast();
  warmObservable.connect();
```

to lettable operators?

When I use:

```
  const warmObservable = this.httpClient.get<Result[]>(url).pipe(publishLast());
  warmObservable.connect();
```

I get error:

`Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.`

Version used: rxjs@5.5.2

Answer (score 2):

The `pipe` method always returns `Observable` as you can see here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L293

So you need to typecast it yourself.

```
const warmObservable = this.httpClient.get<Result[]>(url).pipe(publishLast()) as ConnectableObservable;
warmObservable.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the rxjs 5.5 source (rxjs/util/pipe.ts), the signature for `pipe` with one operator is

```
export function pipe<T, A>(op1: UnaryFunction<T, A>): UnaryFunction<T, A>;
```

so I'd expect `.pipe(publishLast())` to have the connect method.

If I test it outside Angular ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/VrKWqZ?editors=0110)), it does indeed work

```js
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js
const Observable = Rx.Observable
const publishLast = Rx.operators.publishLast

const src = Observable.interval(1000).take(5)
console.log(src)

const warmObservable1 = src.publishLast()
console.log(warmObservable1)  // verify this has connect()

const warmObservable2 = src.pipe(publishLast()) 
console.log(warmObservable2)  // verify this has connect()
warmObservable2.subscribe(console.log)  // outputs '4'
warmObservable2.connect()
```

The questions are:

- is it a version thing (works with 5.5.2)
- is it an Angular thing
- is it an import thing

---

From Ref: [Lettable operators doc](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#what)

> There is a pipe method built into Observable now at Observable.prototype.pipe that сan be used to compose the operators in similar manner to what you're used to with dot-chaining (shown below).
>
> There is also a pipe utility function at rxjs/util/pipe that can be used to build reusable lettable operators from other lettable operators.

The `util` version is the one that works for me, perhaps there's a separate import required for `rxjs/util/pipe`?

Something like

```
import { pipe } from 'rxjs/util/pipe'
```

---

**Best conclusion**

The problem appears to be with the currently distributed typings file `Observable.d.ts`, which types the return value as `Observable`.

Runtime `Observable.js` uses `rxjs/util/pipe` which has a return type of the enclosed operator, therefore the return value will have methods of the operator.

I'm not sure if this can be classed as a bug, but anyway one work-around is to bypass `Observable.d.ts` by casting, e.g

```
const warmObservable = <any>this.httpClient.get<Result[]>(url).pipe(publishLast())
```

Comment: When I click on `pipe` method, it navigates to `pipe<A>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>): Observable<A>;` inside `node_modules\rxjs\Observable.d.ts`

Comment: The  d.ts you navigate to is likely the cause of the error message. The actual runtime `Observable.js` works, as can be seen in the CodePen (it uses the pipe utility function). So, most likely way around it is @martins type cast. I can't test it right now, how did it work for yourself?